# Select records without any related records of some types

Tags: mysql, sql

Basically I have two table

```
articleID 
  1
  2
  3
  4


relatedType | articleID
     3              1
     4              1
     3              2
     4              3
     5              3
     2              4
```

I need to select the articleID that doesn't have any related records with `type > 3`. With this dataset I basically need:

```
articleID
2
4
```

Because their related type contain only 3 and 2.

I con do it with this query:

```
SELECT * FROM article 
   WHERE articleID NOT IN (SELECT articleID FROM relatedTable 
                     ^         WHERE type > 3 GROUP BY portalid ) 
                     |
                     |--- NOT IN does the trick!
```

BUT I would like to avoid nested query because this query is pretty slow. Any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
SELECT * FROM article a
 WHERE NOT EXISTS 
 (SELECT NULL FROM relatedTable b WHERE b.type > 3
  AND b.articleID = a.articleID)
```

Technically, all 3 ways to achieve the desired results (`NOT IN`, `NOT EXISTS`, `LEFT JOIN`) should behave the same (for non-nullable column) and normally generate the same execution plan except mysql where `NOT IN` is not recommended (or wasn't recommended prior to 5.5, maybe it changed).
I'd also blame `GROUP BY` in your original query for poor performance as well...

Comment: I believe EXISTS is even more slow than NOT IN

Comment: But! You were right, the problem was GROUP BY. It added 10sec to the final time (now it's under 0.5 sec)

Comment: @llnk: you may be right about mysql, I haven't worked with it for quite a while... However; I believe it can (and should ) change in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Use OUTER JOIN

```
SELECT a.articleID 
FROM article a LEFT OUTER JOIN relatedTable r
 ON (a.articleID = r.articleID and r.relatedType > 3)
WHERE r.articleID IS NULL
```

CORRECTION:
Sorry, I just realized that the request was not to have those rows listed which has ANY records with type > 3. You can still do it by having a sub-query in the JOIN or by creating a temp table, indexing it and then joining that. Whether any of these are actually faster than the NOT IN sub-query will depend on MySQL version and more importantly table size and stats.

Comment: Interesting... a condition inside ON (...) ?

Comment: Yeap. Actually this is the second time today when I am promoting the condition within the ON () see [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14968414/mysql-truly-distinct-join/14968594#14968594]

Comment: @HamletHakobyan: hm, i didn't check the result

Comment: Yes, I just realized that the request was not to have those rows listed which has ANY records with type > 3. You can still do it by having a subquery in the JOIN or by creating a temp table, indexing it and then joining that. Whethet any of these are actually faster than the NOT IN subquery will depend on MySQL version and more importantly table size and stats.

Answer (score 0):

If you need only article id, try this:

```
SELECT 
   articleID
FROM relatedTable
GROUP BY articleID
HAVING MAX(relatedType) <= 3
```

or you can JOIN this to your `article` table.